# Sort div by content item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible sort `div` by content item? For example I have one `div` that has 3 child `div`.In each child `div` exists different numbers of `span` elements. Can I sort this `div`?

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>1</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery .sortable() on <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659966/jquery-sortable-on-div)

Comment: @JacobH: There's no indication of jQuery UI in the question above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There's no indication of much of anything.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Separately, be sure you've [searched thoroughly](/help/searching) and done other research, made an attempt to solve the problem, etc. Right now this reads as "write this for me" which isn't usually well-received on SO.

Comment: @JacobH: Which is no reason for voting/suggesting to close it as a duplicate of something that there's no indication it duplicates. (It *is* a good reason to vote-to-close. :-) )

Comment: I'd rather offer a solution in the vote to close than none at all. Otherwise I would have simply voted to close based on low quality.

Comment: why i get -1 ???

Comment: You get -1 because people looking at your post see that you are asking a question that could be solved if you did *any* research first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605188/how-to-sort-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: i change title ... i want sort by item count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the nodeList to an array, and then use sort:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv")
var elements = [].slice.call(myDiv.children);

var sorted = elements.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.children.length - b.children.length;
})

console.log('SORTED', sorted)
```

To apply this sorting to the DOM, simply reappend these elements:

```
sorted.forEach(el=>myDiv.appendChild(el));
```

[in action](http://jsbin.com/mihubebonu/edit?output)

Comment: thanks ...it's worked ...Wow